# Calling an R code from Shiny based on UI element

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to call(source) a code based on user input date(to decide path), but can't get to execute this. There's no error, but the called(sourced) code doesn't work(I know this since no file is output). I think I am not able to use eventReactive correctly to get the code executed in following -

```
ui = fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
    titlePanel("MY Outputs")
    ,dateInput("ME_DATE_output",label=h2("Execution Date"), value="2020-05-29")
    ,textOutput('dateSelectionStatement')
    ,hr()
    ,actionButton("calculate", "Calculate Again" )
    ,textOutput("success")
)))

server = function(input, output) { 
ME_DATE_GUI <- reactive({input$ME_DATE_output})
output$dateSelectionStatement <- renderText({paste0('You have selected: ', ME_DATE_GUI()) })

Code_loc <- "K:/Codes/"
code_execution <- eventReactive(input$calculate, {source(paste0(Code_loc,"GUI_trials.r"))}) 

# Print a message for refresh
output$success <- renderText({paste0('Output refreshed for date - ', ME_DATE_GUI())})


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

GUI_trials look like -

```
# Use GUI Reactive to get the date
ME_DATE <- as.Date(ME_DATE_GUI(), format="%Y-%m-%d")

year_N_ME_DATE <- format(ME_DATE,"%Y")
month_N_ME_DATE <- format(ME_DATE,"%m")
month_T_ME_DATE <- months(ME_DATE)

# Location for Outputs
Output_DIR <- "K:/Outputs/"
Output_loc <- paste(Output_DIR,month_N_ME_DATE,". ",month_T_ME_DATE, " ",year_N_ME_DATE,"/",sep="")

success <- "Success"
write.csv(success, paste0(Output_loc,"Success.csv"))
```

The 2 problems are -

1. ME_DATE_GUI is not identified in sourced code(GUI_trials.r). Eeven if I use `ME_DATE <<- renderText({input$ME_DATE_output})` in server part and place `ME_DATE <- as.Date(ME_DATE, format="%Y-%m-%d")` in GUI_trials.r, it's not working. The error is `Error in as.Date.default: do not know how to convert 'ME_DATE' to class “Date”`
2. eventReactive doesn't seem to do anything, i.e., actionButton part is inactive for me.
   Any help is deeply appreciated!

Comment: You haven't provided a MWE because we don't have access to your K drive.

Comment: Sorry, I thought K: drive isn't important, since I gave the code called from there, GUI_trials.r and I can assure you that the folders and path exist!

Comment: It is easier to help if you provide a small but reproducible example so that we can run your code and encounter the same issue that you are facing.

Comment: I think outputs can be copied to any Date named sub-folder, I have "//Outputs/05. May 2020/", which is ME_DATE dependent and that's the objective of code to place CSV output in such folder. Code can be picked from any location(GUI_trials is placed in //Codes/). Main issue is taking date input from Shiny and use that in R code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

server function as -

```
server = function(input, output) { 
ME_DATE_GUI <- reactive({input$ME_DATE_output})
output$dateSelectionStatement <- renderText({paste0('You have selected: ', ME_DATE_GUI()) })
Code_loc <- "K:/Codes/"

observeEvent(input$calculate, {
ME_DATE <- ME_DATE_GUI()
source(paste0(Code_loc,"GUI_trials2.r"), local = TRUE)
# Print a message for refresh
output$success <- renderText({paste0('Output refreshed for date - ', ME_DATE_GUI())})
}) 
}
```

followed by change in `GUI_trials2.R` code as -

```
# Use ME_DATE from Shiny
ME_DATE <- as.Date(ME_DATE, format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

solved this issue!
Key was to use `local=TRUE` in `source` statement.